# Setting a timeout for Ajax.BeginForm() in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, timeout, microsoft-ajax

I have a query that takes a while to return results on our staging box and it has been wired to the front-end using an ASP.NET MVC `Ajax.BeginForm()`.  I have searched the help and the internet but can't seem to find a way to extend the timeout for this operation.

Answer (score 0):

Add NoAsyncTimeout to the Controller that the form is calling.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [NoAsyncTimeout]
    public async Task<string> MyActionMethod(SomeClass model)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100000);
        return "Finished";
    }
```